# Reload Windows environnement variables on a Commande Prompt without closing it

Tags: windows, cmd

How do I reload Windows environment variables on a Command line (CMD) without closing it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

```
setlocal
... do part  of the script
endlocal
setlocal
... do part 2 of the script
endlocal
setlocal
... do part 3 of the script
endlocal
```

for as many parts as you want.

The downside is that any changes to the environment that you want to save will be lost at the `endlocal` command.

There are two ways around this

```
setlocal
... do part n of the script
endlocal&set keepme=%keepme%&set keepme2=%keepme2%...
```

or

```
setlocal
... do part n of the script
set keepme>>keepmefile.txt
endlocal
for /f "delims=" %%a in (keepmefile.txt) do set %%a
```

which saves the values starting `keepme` in a file and then reloads them after the `endlocal` is executed. (I tend to reserve a prefix of `$` on variablenames I want to preserve for such purposes)